# Search a text in a text file and print in CMD prompt using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, cmd

I want to write a batch file (.bat). Using the batch file I want to search for a unique text in a text file and print the line containing the text into console window as output. Search criteria is user input.

Which batch code is required for this task?

For example below is the content of the .txt file.

> "Command Prompt, also known as cmd.exe or cmd (after its executable file name), **is the command-line interpreter on Windows NT, Windows CE, OS/2 and  eComStation** operating systems. It is the counterpart of COMMAND.COM in DOS and Windows 9x systems (where it is also called "MS-DOS Prompt"), and analogous to the Unix shells used on Unix-like systems. The initial version of Command Prompt for Windows NT was developed by Therese Stowell.[1]"

I want to write a batch script using Windows standard commands where user inputs the search string like `Windows CE` and the entire line with this string gets output in command prompt window.

For example on user inputs `Windows CE` the output should be:

```
is the command-line interpreter on Windows NT, Windows CE, OS/2 and eComStation
```

Comment: @Mofi: Your edit had changed the original sense of the question. In your "improved text" formatting it is easy to see that the desired output is the second line of the .txt file, but the original question describe an entirely different problem! I don't know what is the search criteria used by the OP to extract such part from the .txt file so I asked the user about this point, but IMO modifying the input data in a way that it matches what _you think_ is the search criteria is not the right way to understand this problem...

Comment: @Mofi: Note that there is no way that Windows Notepad show a one-line file as it appears in your "improved text" modification, but the original OP's formatting is entirely correct in this sense.

Comment: @Zoso619 What are the rules which define which part of a long paragraph stored in the text file in a single line should be output to console on having found a search string in that paragraph?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create a batch file for this function.  It already exists in the `find` tool in all versions of Windows that can be called from any `cmd` prompt.  Here are some details on how to use it: [How to Use Find from the command prompt](http://www.howtogeek.com/206097/how-to-use-find-from-the-windows-command-prompt/)

EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:

The `find` syntax is pretty straightforward.  You seem to know the file that you want to search in and you know how to prompt the user for the string:

```
set /P search_string= Enter the string you would like to search for:
find "%search_string%" C:\ServiceLog%_store%.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. but its a part of my program. i have already created code where the batch file access to a restricted path and pic some log and create a note pad in my local drive. through the same tool i want to write a code where user gives input and it reads the notepad placed in local and fetch the entire row based on the search criteria if it matches

Comment: Then just call `find` from within your batch file with the desired parameters.

Comment: could you pls share the code for the above example that i have mentioned ? i am very new to batch programming. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Your example is too generic, especially because you mention restricted paths, local locations, etc.  It's also not clear what your constraints are for the search criteria.  Please post the code that you have written so far and what part of it doesn't work.  That way we can view your environmental constraints and get a better sense of what will fix it.

Comment: `Echo Copying the file in your C drive...

set /p ServiceLog = <"\\ptw0\LogFiles\Service\%_date%\FunctionService%_store%.log"
if exist "C:\ServiceLog%_store%.txt" del "C:\ServiceLog%_store%.txt"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('type "\\ptw0\LogFiles\Service\%_date%\FunctionService%_store%.log"') DO @echo %%f >>"C:\ServiceLog%_store%.txt"
Echo Please update the details and Save the file..
Pause
Echo.
Echo Select an option :
Echo.

Echo 1. Update the file
Echo 2. Exit
Echo.
Echo Select an option :

set/p option=

cls`

Comment: this is the code for coping it in c drive.then i want to find a text from the notepad and display the entire row on the console.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but here in command prompt the entire text present in the note pad is getting printed, i just want to print the single row where the search criteria is found.is it possible in DOS? if it is how?

Comment: if the entire text is getting printed, then the whole text is just one line. How should `cmd` decide, what you want to see?

Comment: The `find` command returns all the lines in the file where the search string is found.  If it's returning the "whole file", then either the whole file is one line, or the search string appears in every line of the file.

Comment: @Zoso619: What you did _not_ said us is _the output_ you want given such input file and user input string! Please, include this info in your question (does _not_ use comments for large descriptions) and include the critera that should be used to extract such output. Do NOT use code to explain this, but just plain English please!

Comment: In other words, you said: _" print the single row where the search criteria is found"_, but you did NOT defined what  the "search critera" is.

Comment: @Aacini to be fair - Mekki DID define the search criteria (user input, for example "Windows CE")  The problem is, his file is just one long line (wich notepad happily wraps to fit into the notepad-window) and he expects to get just one of those "notepad-lines" - which is not possible with batch, because batch can't know, where notepad wraps the lines.

Comment: @Stephan: Humm, I don't think so... In the **original question** the OP never mentioned "line", but "row", and the output he wants was comprised of the last two words from first row: "is the", plus the entire second row excepting the last word: "operating", so certainly there is not any search criteria here. The question as currently appears, that indicate "line" and with the desired output placed in second line of the .txt file, is product of [Mofi's edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34954047/revisions) that, in my opinion, had completely changed the original sense of this question...

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below separate the lines from input file in phrases, where a *phrase* is a string delimited by commas or points.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set /P "userString=Enter the search string: "

rem Process all lines in file
for /F "delims=" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "line=%%a"

   rem Split all phrases in line
   call :splitPhrases

   rem Process each phrase
   for /L %%i in (1,1,!numPhrases!) do (

      rem If the user string appears in this phrase
      if "!phrase[%%i]:%userString%=!" neq "!phrase[%%i]!" (
         rem ... show it
         echo !phrase[%%i]!
      )

   )
)
goto :EOF


:splitPhrases
set "numPhrases=0"

:nextPhrase
   for /F "tokens=1* delims=.," %%a in ("!line!") do (
      set /A numPhrases+=1
      set "phrase[!numPhrases!]=%%a"
      set "line=%%b"
   )
if defined line goto nextPhrase
exit /B
```

Output example:

```
Enter the search string: Windows CE
 Windows CE
```

If you want better answers, please post better questions...